# How much bandwidth is required to run an app that will be used by ten thousand users at the same time

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting

Could you please tell me how much bandwidth should I look for to run an web based application (total file size 3.4 mb) which will be used by ten thousand users at the same time?

App Details:
web languages used: PHP, HTML, Jquery
Database: MySql

If possible could you please suggest me a good hosting service provider?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Bandwidth**

It is hard to estimate that bandwidth usage based on the small amount of information you have provided. What does the app do? Will all 10k users be using it at the same time and every day? The easiest and most accurate way to estimate usage would be to test it on a smaller scale with say 10, 50, or 100 users and multiply the bandwidth used.

**Hosting**

As far as recommending a host - are you looking for a US server or somewhere else? What is your budget? Will your disk usage grow as your app is used (estimated need?)? Managed or un-managed?

--

I realize this answer isn't exactly complete yet, if you provide some more information I will edit my answer to be more helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on Page size and how fast you want them to download the file...

**Formula**

Page Size + File Size x Amount of Users / time x Amount of Users

**Example**

Page size is 200kb
File Size is 3.4mb
User Amount is 10,000
Target Time on Download is 1min

Page Size
0.2mb = 204.8kb = 1.6mbit

File Size
3.4mb = 3,686.4kb = 28.8mbit

**Working out the Requirement for a 80sec Download + Page Size**

1.6mbit + 28.8mbit = 30.4mb x 10,000 = 304,000mbit / 80 secs = 3800mbit (3800mbit required for serving 10,000 users at 46kb/sec each) - Pretty slow, see conclusion.

Working out the speed = 3,686.4kb / 80secs = 46kb/sec

**Conclusion**

A Dedicated / VPS will not do the job or your need to pay a lot of money for a highend NIC on the machine. Your best of hosting your file on a CDN.